# Include comment feed link on blogoverflow.com posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog-overflow

WordPress automatically creates an RSS feed for comments on blog posts. These are of the form `<permalink>/feed/`, so for example a post on my own blog http://www.texdev.net/2011/07/17/which-siunitx-options-to-set-globally/ has a comment feed http://www.texdev.net/2011/07/17/which-siunitx-options-to-set-globally/feed/. This can be help when people post a comment which they might get a reply to: they have a way to be informed if one turns up.

However, the *visibility* of this functionality depends on the WordPress theme used. In the theme I use for my own blog ([The Journalist](http://lucianmarin.com/page/themes)) includes appropriate links, but the 'out of the box' WordPress ones do not. Currently, the blogoverflow design does not include the appropriate links either, so people comments may wonder what they can do to see feedback (see for example http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/a-regular-answer-the-unanswered-slot/#comments). Would it be possible to add the appropriate link to the blogoverflow theme(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion.  I've added this in, though you might see a cached page for a bit, so check back if you don't see it immediately.